# How to get a list of directories or 'none'?

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

With PowerShell I want to check a directory (full name in `$PathOutput`) if it contains other directories. If this path does not contain other directories, I want a variable `$FailedTests` to have the string 'none', otherwise the variable `$FailedTests` should contain every found directory (non-recursive), either in a different line, or comma-seperated, or whatever.

I have tried the following code:

```
$DirectoryInfo = Get-ChildItem $PathOutput | Measure-Object
if ($directoryInfo.Count -eq 0)
{
  $FailedTests = "none"
} else {
  $FailedTests = Get-ChildItem  $PathOutput -Name -Attributes D | Measure-Object
}
```

but it generates the following error:

```
Get-ChildItem : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'attributes'.
At D:\Testing\Data\Powershell\LoadRunner\LRmain.ps1:52 char:62
+   $FailedTests = Get-ChildItem  $PathOutput -Name -Attributes <<<<  D | Measure-Object
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Get-ChildItem], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NamedParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetChildItemCommand
```

I am using Powershell 2.0 on Windows Server 2008.

I would prefer a solution which uses `Get-ChildItem` or whetever only once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is actually rather self-explanatory: `Get-ChildItem` (in PowerShell v2) doesn't have a parameter `-Attributes`. That parameter (as well as the parameter `-Directory`) was added with PowerShell v3. In PowerShell v2 you need to use a `Where-Object` filter for removing unwanted results, e.g. like this:

```
$DirectoryInfo = Get-ChildItem $PathOutput | Where-Object {
    $_.Attributes -band [IO.FileAttributes]::Directory
}
```

or like this:

```
$DirectoryInfo = Get-ChildItem $PathOutput | Where-Object {
    $_.GetType() -eq [IO.DirectoryInfo]
}
```

or (better) like this:

```
$DirectoryInfo = Get-ChildItem $PathOutput | Where-Object { $_.PSIsContainer }
```

You can output the folder list, or "none" if there weren't any, like this:

```
if ($DirectoryInfo) {
  $DirectoryInfo | Select-Object -Expand FullName
} else {
  'none'
}
```

because an empty result (`$null`) is [interpreted as `$false`](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/2006/12/24/boolean-values-and-operators/).

Comment: Thanks a lot, exactly what I needed, and it is working as well!!

Answer (score 1):

You could maybe do something like this? This way you also do not have to get the childitems twice.

```
$PathOutput = "C:\Users\David\Documents"
$childitem = Get-ChildItem $PathOutput | ?{ $_.PSIsContainer } | select fullname, name

if ($childitem.count -eq 0)
{
$FailedTests = "none"
}
else
{
$FailedTests = $childitem
}
$FailedTests
```

Comment: Does not seem to work. If the directory in question does not contain anything, still the 'else' part of the if statement is used. $FailedTests is empty in that case ...